# $\int_\mathbb{R} f d\lambda = 2 \int_{(0,\infty)} f d\lambda$ for $f(-x)=f(x)$ and $f(0)=0$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

We have a measure space $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\lambda)$ and a measurable, numerical, non-negative function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow[0,\infty]$ with $f(-x)=f(x)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ and $f(0)=0$. Then:
$$\int_\mathbb{R} f d\lambda = 2 \int_{(0,\infty)} f d\lambda$$

Since f is not Riemann integrable how do I show this?

Comment: Split the integral and use a substitution.

Comment: $f(0)=0$ is useless. You can shorten your title and your text.

Comment: Is $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure? For general measures this is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you integrate w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure, you can pull apart the integral by first separating the integrand via indicator functions
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x) d\lambda(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)(\mathbb{1}_{x \geq 0}(x) + \mathbb{1}_{x<0}(x))d\lambda(x)
$$
then pull apart the integral
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)(\mathbb{1}_{x \geq 0}(x) + \mathbb{1}_{x<0}(x))d\lambda
=
\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\mathbb{1}_{x \geq 0}(x)d\lambda(x) + \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\mathbb{1}_{x<0}(x)d\lambda(x)
$$
pull the indicators back in the boundaries of the integrals
$$
=\int_0^\infty f(x)d\lambda(x) + \int_{-\infty}^0 f(x)d\lambda(x)
$$
and finally use the symmetry of $f$ around $0$ to obtain the result
$$
= 2 \int_0^\infty f(x)d\lambda(x)
$$

Answer (score 2):

This is false. Take $\mathrm d\lambda = \delta_{-1}$ the dirac measure at the point $x=-1$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$. Then
$$
\int_{\Bbb R} f\,\mathrm d\lambda = 1 \neq 0 = 2\int_{(0,\infty)} f\,\mathrm d\lambda.
$$